# Using Python Pylons, what is a good way to use an authentication cookie throughout an application?

Tags: python, pylons

I'm using Python + Pylons to authenticate a user, and am then sending a unique md5 sum and storing it as a cookie to verify the user at every page load. Where in my application is the best place to put the cookie handling functions so that they are accessible throughout my application? Should I declare a global variable such as, USER, that would be accessible throughout the application storing important values like first name, last name, etc ... of the logged in user? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you've already got the userid in a cookie, you just want to make it more accessible. You'll probably find it useful to have a simple helper function that takes the request and returns the user.

```
def get_user(request):
    """ Load the user from the request, or None if unauthenticated."""
    if not hasattr(request, '_cookie_user'):
        # parse the userid from the cookie
        # make sure you actually trust this cookie by signing it
        # or storing it in something that's already protected
        # like beaker instead of a raw cookie
        userid = request.cookies['mycookie']
        request._cookie_user = DBSession.query(User).get(userid)
        if user and user.is_active:
            request._cookie_user = user
    return getattr(request, '_cookie_user', None)
```

Later in your app you can simply call `user = get_user(request)`.

Comment: Thanks. Which file would you recommend putting this in so that it gets included with every page?

Comment: "every page" ? I'd suggest putting it in your lib/base.py or in your lib/helpers.py module probably.

Answer (score 0):

A database or memcache is usually the place to store this kind of information.

Pylons provides Beaker: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pylons-webframework/en/latest/sessions.html